# Post data to mysql db based on user input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I wasn't really sure how to word the question thus meaning I couldn't find anything on the web, I will try to describe it a little better.

So I have 3 input radio buttons, the value is equal to 3 names e.g - "Sam" "Tom" "Harry". At the moment if a user selects "Sam" it posts that name to a specified column using PHP PDO.

What I want to change is if they do pick "Sam" Post the name still, but also post the img, path to another column. I wasn't sure how to go about adding this feature maybe an if statement would be sufficient because at the moment they can only pick from three names.

name - nameImg

Sam  - images/avatar/sam.png

```
<?php
include 'users.php';

echo $_SESSION['id'];

$u = User::Create($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['avatar'],$_POST['name']);

if($u == 1){ header('location: /admin'); } 
else if ($u == 2){ echo "Name already taken"; } 
else { echo "There was an error with the sign up -- SEND BACK TO LOGIN WITH VALIDATION"; }
?>
```

To clarify I want to post the image path of the avatar they pick via radio buttons on signup.

Updated html -

```
        <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio inline">
          <input class="startrbtn" name="name" value="sam" checked="checked" type="radio" style="margin-top:-3px;">
        </label>
        <label class="radio inline">
          <input class="startrbtn" name="name" value="tom" type="radio">
        </label>
        <label class="radio inline">
          <input class="startrbtn" name="name" value="harry" type="radio">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Method

```
public function Create($name,$password,$email,$avatar)
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME", "NAME", "PASSWORD");

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT username FROM login WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if (!empty($result->username)){
            return 2;
        } else {
```

Comment: Show the code in your Create method of the User Class.